# Where jenkins store build files result?

Tags: jenkins, build, jobs

I am wondering if there is a way to get the files result of a Jenkins build.

I configure Jenkins to create the build, so it successfully pull my gitlab and then compile my project. So it should have my files and the compilation result stored somewhere right?

The only files I could see in the last build for my job directory are :

- build.xml
- changelog.xml
- log

Thanks for your help, really appreciate that !

Thomas

Comment: Finally I found those files in `$JENKINS_HOME/workspace/yourjobname`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Workspace will keep the latest build, the legacy will be kept inside the jenkins master slave under

```
$JENKINS_HOME/yourjobname/builds/yourbuildernumer
```

Br,

Tim

Comment: Actually the build files are not in it. I finally found those in `$JENKINS_HOME/workspace/yourjobname`

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

Comment: You need to archive your build artifacts in order to find them under the path that Tim mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the jenkins build files:
`/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<yourjobname>`
`builds`

Answer (score 1):

you can find it under

```
jenkins_home/jobs/YourProjectName/builds
```